# Transparent UIPickerView on blurred UIVisualEffectView: White flashes on device orientation

Tags: swift, uipickerview

The title pretty much says it. Even though I don't have white in my UIPickerView, the orientation change animation trigged by the viewWillTransitionToSize method renders the view with white cells during the animation, which looks quite ugly. The only workaround so far is to hide the PickerView during the animation, which is less than ideal.